# Unramified covers of the affine line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $\kappa$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0.
Let $X$ be a smooth connected curve defined over $\kappa$, such that there is an unramified cover

$$\pi:X\to \mathbb{A}^1_\kappa$$
Is $\pi$ necessarily an isomorphism?

Of course the assertion is easy if $\kappa=\mathbb{C}$ (by the simply connectedness of $\mathbb{C}$), but is false if $ch(\kappa)=p$: just take the map

$$V(y^p-y-x)\to \mathbb{A}^1_\kappa,\;\; (x,y)\mapsto x$$

Comment: What do you mean by a smooth curve? For instance, if you allow that $X$ is disconnected with zero-dimensional connected components, then the statement "$\pi$ is an isomorphism" is false, even if $k = \mathbb{C}$. If "smooth curve" means "smooth connected curve", then the statement is still false. Your morphism $X\to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ is unramified and surjective. This implies, as $X$ is integral, that $\pi$ is flat hence etale. But it is not necessarily finite etale, even if it is surjective. (I leave that as an exercise for now.) In any case, the fact that....

Comment: ....a finite etale cover $X$ of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ with  $X$ connected is an isomorphism can be proven as follows. 1) The statement is true over $k=\mathbb{C}$ as you notice. 2) It is therefore true whenever $k\subset \mathbb{C}$ (exercise). 3) Any $\pi$ as in the question descends to a finite etale morphism over a countable algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Since every such field embeds into $\mathbb{C}$, we reduce to 2).

Comment: Ok, i meant smooth connected curve and i meant an unramified cover, not just a surjective morphism. I corrected the question.
There is no handier way to prove it in this case?

Comment: Yes, it follows from Riemann-Hurwitz, because $X\to \mathbb{A}^1$ finite etale extends to a finite surjective morphism $\overline{X} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ which is either unramified or ramifies only at $\infty$.

Comment: Ok, but Riemann Hurwitz is true only for smooth irreducible projective curves. How do you know that you Can choose a closure of X which is smooth?

Comment: A smooth   connected variety is irreducible. This is a good exercise to think about. Let $X$ be a smooth quasi-projective curve. Choose a locally closed embedding $X\subset \mathbb{P}^N$. Let $X'$ be the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Since $X$ is open in $X'$, we have that $X'$ is a projective irreducible curve. Let $\overline{X}$ be the normalization of $X'$. Note that $\overline{X}$ is a normal projective irreducible one-dimensional variety over $k$. Since normal varieties are regular in codimension one, $\overline{X}$ is smooth.

Comment: Ok, i understand your argument. But it seems to work also in positive characteristic.

Comment: No it doesn't, because then Riemann-Hurwitz won't help, because the morphism $X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ could be wildly ramified.